# how can I add an auto indent feature after colon in tkinter gui in python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

I am making a **text editor** it has all the features but not an **auto-indent** feature which can **automatically add spaces after loops or conditions**. Please tell me how can I make, and please try to give a code which can do it. I am making this in Tkinter and want this function in the text widget. I had made this text editor.[image]

I made this in Tkinter so please help me to give a code for auto-indent. I had tried for firing events whenever a user presses **':'** button to give an indent in the next line but it does not follow the pattern of multilevel indenting. like

```
    for i in range(100):
        if i==5:
            break
        else:
            print('got till '+str(i))
```

but my code does not follow like this it only adds space in the first line so the code looks like.

```
   for i in range(100):
      if i==5:
      break
   else:
      print('got till '+str(i))
```

so it is a bit tricky. Please comment for any related info or question but please answer me.

Comment: That image of text editor is what I had made.

Comment: You just need to determine the indentation of the line with the ":" and then add whatever amount you want, rather than hard-coding a specific amount.

Comment: provide me a hint or code because I am not able to get these things work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to get the indentation from the current line and add the new level of indentation.

Here's a complete working example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import re

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def autoindent(event):
    # the text widget that received the event
    widget = event.widget

    # get current line
    line = widget.get("insert linestart", "insert lineend")

    # compute the indentation of the current line
    match = re.match(r'^(\s+)', line)
    current_indent = len(match.group(0)) if match else 0

    # compute the new indentation
    new_indent = current_indent + 4

    # insert the character that triggered the event,
    # a newline, and then new indentation
    widget.insert("insert", event.char + "\n" + " "*new_indent)

    # return 'break' to prevent the default behavior
    return "break"

text.bind(":", autoindent)

root.mainloop()
```